# Python determine whether an exception was thrown (regardless of whether it is caught or not)

Tags: python

I am writing tests for some legacy code that is littered with catch-all constructs like

```
try:
    do_something()
    do_something_else()

    for x in some_huge_list():
        do_more_things()

except Exception:
    pass
```

and I want to tell whether an exception was thrown inside the try block.

I want to avoid introducing changes into the codebase just to support a few tests and I don't want to make the `except` cases more specific for fear of unintentionally introducing regressions.

Is there a way of extracting information about exceptions that were raised and subsequently handled from the runtime? Or some function with a similar API to `eval`/`exec`/`apply`/`call` that either records information on every raised exception, lets the user supply an exception handler that gets run first, or lets the user register a callback that gets run on events like an exception being raised or caught.

If there isn't a way to detect whether an exception was thrown without getting under the (C)Python runtime in a really nasty way, what are some good strategies for testing code with catch-all exceptions inside the units you're testing?

Comment: Why not just print something inside the `except` block?

Comment: Do you care if an exception was thrown and handled inside `do_something()`?

Comment: `except Exception as e: print(e)`

Comment: You generally can't after the fact, because *once a function exits* (Python 2) or the `try..except` block is done (Python 3) all traces of exceptions are cleared.

Comment: One semi-solution I've been toying with is adding a whole bunch of `def foo_exception_hook(*args, **kwargs): pass` functions, calling them as `foo_exception_hook(e)` inside the exception handler, and then targeting them with `mock.patch` in the body of my test code so I can extract the exception object with the `call_with_args` method on magic mocks. I borrowed this concept from emacs. I don't like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only realistic option is to instrument the `except` handlers.

Python does record exception information, which is retrievable with [`sys.exc_info()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info), but this information is *cleared* when a function exits (Python 2) or the `try` statement is done (Python 3).

Comment: The claim that this is the only option sounds incorrect to me.  I think it would be possible by [ab]using the [system trace function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.settrace).

Comment: @wim: then by all means try to do that, but that is going to be *painfully* slow. I don't consider that a practical option.

Comment: @wim: and does that make this answer so unhelpful as to be worthy of downvoting?

Comment: Right, I never said that it was a good idea.  Just possible.  Coverage uses this to see which lines are visited, for example.

Comment: @wim: sure, and coverage uses a C extension to keep that manageable (the slowdown is still easily measurable though).

Answer (score -1):

A good strategy would be testing observable behaviour. Since exceptions were explicitly excluded from the observable behaviour I do not think you should be testing whether an exception was raised or not.